# Drop down button flutter error exception with Null value

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-maps, chrome-app-developer-tool

[image]

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building MyHomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _MyHomePageState#a3bdf(tickers: tracking 1 ticker)):
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Marker{markerId: MarkerId(First Marker), alpha:[image] 1.0, anchor: Offset(0.5, 1.0), consumeTapEvents: false, draggable: false, flat: false, icon: Instance of 'BitmapDescriptor', infoWindow: InfoWindow{title: First Marker, snippet: null, anchor: Offset(0.5, 0.0)}, position: LatLng(37.42267, -122.0838), rotation: 0.0, visible: true, zIndex: 0.0, onTap: null, onDragStart: null, onDrag: null, onDragEnd: null}.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 888 pos 15:

```
'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'


    DropdownButton(
                    value: selectedMarker,
                onChanged: ((Marker? marker) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedMarker = marker!;
                  });
                  print("selectedmarker value ${selectedMarker}");
                  mapController.moveCamera(CameraUpdate.newLatLng(marker!.position));
                }),
            items: markers.map((marker) {
              return DropdownMenuItem(
                value: marker,
                child: Text(marker.markerId.value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
```

This is the dropdownbutton widget which is causing the error. Now the thing I want to achieve is that after selecting an item from the menu the Marker on the maps gets selected. that is done. Now if i press directions button then the marker will follow polylinepoints. When i press the button this error occurs. Directions button code is given below:

```
IconButton(
   onPressed: () async {
         if(selectedMarker.markerId == MarkerId("First Marker")){
           controller = AnimationController(
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
               vsync: this,
               );
                 selectedMarker = markers[0];
       for (int i = 0; i < polylinePoints.length && i + 1 != polylinePoints.length; i = i + 1) {
                                markerAnimation = LatLngTween(
                                    begin: polylinePoints[i],
                                    end: polylinePoints[i + 1])
                                    .animate(controller);
                                markerAnimation.addListener(() {
                                  setState(() {
          Marker marker1 = Marker(markerId: MarkerId("First Marker",
                       ),icon:BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
                                    );
                                    print("This is marker1 ${marker1}");
                                    marker1 = marker1.copyWith(
                                      positionParam: markerAnimation.value,
                                    );
                                    ///will be right back
                                    markers[0] = marker1;
                                    // _addFirstMarker(Variables.point);
                                  });
                                });
                                controller.forward();
                                await Future.delayed(
                                    const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
                              }
                            }
                            if(selectedMarker.markerId == MarkerId("Second Marker")){
                              controller = AnimationController(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                vsync: this,
                              );
                 selectedMarker = markers[1];
     for (int i = 0; i < polylinePoints1.length && i + 1 != polylinePoints1.length; i = i + 1) {
                                markerAnimation = LatLngTween(
                                    begin: polylinePoints1[i],
                                    end: polylinePoints1[i + 1])
                                    .animate(controller);
                                markerAnimation.addListener(() {
                                  setState(() {
          Marker marker1 = Marker(markerId: MarkerId("Second Marker",
            ),icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
                                    );
                                    marker1 = marker1.copyWith(
                                      positionParam: markerAnimation.value,
                                    );
                                    markers[1] = marker1;
                                    // _addFirstMarker(Variables.point);
                                  });
                                });
                                controller.forward();
                                await Future.delayed(
                                    const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
                              }
                            }
                            if(selectedMarker.markerId == MarkerId("Third Marker")){
                              controller = AnimationController(
                                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                                vsync: this,
                              ); selectedMarker = markers[2];
     for (int i = 0; i < polylinePoints2.length && i + 1 != polylinePoints2.length; i = i + 1) {
                                markerAnimation = LatLngTween(
                                    begin: polylinePoints2[i],
                                    end: polylinePoints2[i + 1])
                                    .animate(controller);
                                markerAnimation.addListener(() {
                                  setState(() {
          Marker marker1 = Marker(markerId: MarkerId("Third Marker",
           ), icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(BitmapDescriptor.hueGreen),
                                    );
                                    marker1 = marker1.copyWith(
                                      positionParam: markerAnimation.value,
                                    );
                                    markers[2] = marker1;
                                    // _addFirstMarker(Variables.point);
                                  });
                                });
                                controller.forward();
                                await Future.delayed(
                                    const Duration(milliseconds: 50));
                              }
                            }
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.directions))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of a `DropDownButton` must exist among the values of the items.

When you tap for example the first button you do

```
selectedMarker = markers[0];
```

but some lines below it assign a new marker to it

```
markers[0] = marker1;
```

Now `selectedMarker` no longer exists inside `markers` and this is not allowed. I believe should do the

```
selectedMarker = markers[0];
```

right after you do

```
markers[0] = marker1;
```

and not before it.
Same with the other ones.

Comment: I have already set selectedMarker = markers[0] in the initState(). So it is not empty.

Comment: @SamiulIslam it's not about it being empty but about it being different than one of the markers, like I also explain in this answer. By doing `markers[0] = marker1;` you are removing the marker that was originally in `markers[0]`, which is the `selectedMarker`

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I understand what was actually happening,

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the initial value. When the initial value of the dropdown is not available in your item list.
e.g.

```dart
DropdownButton<String>(
            value: "z",
            onChanged: ((marker) {}),
            items: ["a", "b", "c"].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
```

In the above example the initial value "z" is not available in the item list so the dropdown button raises an assertion. A dropdown button requires a value property that should be available in the item list.
Assign initial value as below,

```dart
var selectedMarker = markers.first;
```

Comment: I have already set selectedMarker = markers[0] in the initState(). So it is not empty.

Comment: @SamiulIslam you have initialized selectedMarker value but inside onPressed() method value is changed and the changed value is not available in markers for this reason dropdown arises this error. Remember with dropdown, the value should be non-zero, unique, and not duplicate one in the list.

Comment: Yes, Now it is done. Got solution.

Comment: Just added markers[0] = marker1; this after every time changed were being made in the marker.